# SAPUI5: Difference between invalidate and rerender

Tags: javascript, rendering, sapui5

After digging into the code a bit I see that `invalidate()` on a control will increase a counter which seems to mark the control as invalidated.
This seems to lead to a rerender.

So if you have a control that you want rerendered, **is it better practice to use `invalidate()` or `rerender()`?**

How does a rerender actually get triggered? (other than by explicitly invoking it of course)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both are marked as "protected", meaning you should not call any of them unless you are really deep into developing custom controls.

A control gets invalidated when (for example) a property is changed. In that case you usually want to re-render the control, that's why setters call invalidate by default.

When you overwrite your invalidate method in your custom control, you can analyze the source of the invalidation and then decide whether you really want to rerender etc. See for example the unified.Shell which decides what to do on invalidate based on the source:
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/resources/sap/ui/unified/Shell-dbg.js line 1539ff

Again: Protected means that it should not be called from the outside (and that it should not be necessary, except for debugging).

Comment: Thanks for that information. I'm still not really understanding when it is better to call invalidate vs. rerender. Perhaps you invoke invalidate() when you want to suggest to the framework to re-render a control, and you invoke rerender() when you really want to re-render (and not even provide an opportunity in the invalidate function to potentially avoid the rerender (or do a partial rerender)?
Does that sound on the right track?

Comment: Also, do you know the mechanism that actually kicks of the re-render (which I guess would also be traversing the invalidate chain)? Some sort of timer? For example, in Flex apps I think it's based on frames...

Comment: Usually if you want to use invalidate or rerender inside your application, something else is broken. Maybe you could describe the problem you are trying to solve so I can understand your problem. To repeat: The best practice is to use neither.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it better practice to use `invalidate()` or `rerender()`?

### As an application developer

Neither `invalidate()` nor `rerender()` should be used as they're not public APIs.

### As a *control* developer

Usually, the framework already manages rerendering of the controls automatically if one of the control settings (properties, aggregations, or associations) changes. But if it's still required to trigger the rerendering explicitly, the API **`invalidate()` should be favored** over `rerender()` because:

- `rerender()`

  - renders the control synchronously (blocking the main/UI thread)
  - works only when the control has been rendered before (no initial rendering possible)
  - does not combine multiple state changes into a single rerendering
  - causes additional layout trashing
  - has become **deprecated** since 1.70.
- `invalidate()`, on the other hand, just adds the control to a collection of *to-be-rendered* controls so that it can be rendered together with them in one process **asynchronously** (currently in the next browser task using `setTimeout(fn, 0)`).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered such thing in my work recently. I am fixing an animation issue but the bad thing is I have to start the animation after rendering. If that is all I can handle it, but the worse thing is the control rendering twice. When the first rendering happen, the animation start to do, but the second rendering comes immediately and the DOM was restructed, then the animation is terminated and the effect is like no animation executed. After investigate the code, I found there is a place invoke render() method which will execute render immediately. After change it to invoke invalidated() method, it looks the animation works well. It looks multiple invalidate() method invocation only cause executing render once.